# Singular or Plural words in this sentence

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I wrote:

> ... and the leaf **nodes** are either labelled with **a terminal** (anchor) or **a non-terminal symbol**, which are marked with the substitution marker.

Vs.

> ... and the leaf **nodes** are either labelled with **terminals** (anchor) or **non-terminal symbols**, which are marked with the substitution marker.

In fact each node is marked either with **a single** terminal or **a single** non-terminal. But when I use them as plural, I don't know what to use.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, the phrasing

> terminals or non-terminal symbols

is slightly incorrect, since you are possibly mixing the adjective "terminal" with the modified noun "symbols". The full phrase is

> terminal symbols or non-terminal symbols

so, the correct phrasing would be

> terminal or non-terminal symbols   *(this is the multiple)*
>   a terminal or a non-terminal symbol  *(this is the singular)*

Which one gets used will depend whether there are multiple symbols attached to each node.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, each node gets just one terminal or non-terminal.

Comment: You might make it explicit that each node gets one symbol by saying **each leaf node is marked with a terminal or a non-terminal symbol.**

Comment: "Terminal" is sometimes nominalized as short for "terminal node", so would be acceptable, but it is clearer when spelled out more fully as suggested.